# PDF File its corrupted in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, pdf

im sending a PDF file and getting it in req.body in NodeJS, the req.body starts with this:

```
%PDF-1.3
```

and end with

```
0000001041 00000 n 
    0000001134 00000 n 
    0000001226 00000 n 
    0000001320 00000 n 
    0000001418 00000 n 
    0000150613 00000 n 
    0000150725 00000 n 
    trailer
    <<
    /Size 20
    /Root 19 0 R
    /Info 18 0 R
    >>
    startxref
    150829
    %%EOF
```

But when i save in a pdf file with this code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
        fs.writeFile("sdf.pdf", req.body.file, function(err) {
         if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("The file was saved!");
            }
        });
```

I cant open the file..Now i send the file and i download the file at same time to check if its equals and yes it is.
I checked the length and its the same, and the content its the same...
Whats wrong?

Comment: Ever got it fixed? I'm struggling now with sending a PDF file with express.

Comment: Yes, only converti from base64 and it worls

Comment: I've got mine working by piping to `res.socket` rather than `res`. Don't know exactly why it wasn't working, but the file was encoded slightly differently

Comment: Had the same issue; fixed it thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45157605/node-request-write-to-file-corrupt