# Node request write to file corrupt

Tags: node.js

I have a get request in node that successfully receives data from API.

When I pipe that response directly to a file like this, it works, the file created is a valid, readable pdf (as i expect to receive from the API).

```
var http = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

http.get(
{
  url:'',
  headers:{}
})
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./report.pdf'));
```

Simple, however the file gets corrupted if I use the event emitters of the request like this

```
  http.get(
{
  url:'',
  headers:{}
})
.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log(err);
})
.on('data', function(data) {
  file += data;
})
.on('end', function() {
    var stream = fs.createWriteStream('./report.pdf');
    stream.write(file, function() {
      stream.end();
    });
});
```

I have tried all manner of writing this file and it always ends in a totally blank pdf - the only time the pdf is valid is via the pipe method.

When i console log the events, the sequence seems to be correct - ie, all chunks received and then the `end` fires at the end.

It's making things impossible to do anything after the pipe. What is pipe doing differently to the writestream ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume that you initialize `file` as a string:

```
var file = '';
```

Then, in your `data` handler, you add the new chunk of data to it:

```
file += data;
```

However, this performs an implicit conversion to (UTF-8-encoded) strings. If the data is actually binary, like with a PDF, this will invalidate the output data.

Instead, you want to collect the `data` chunks, which are `Buffer` instances, and use [`Buffer.concat()`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_concat_list_totallength) to concatenate all those buffers into one large (binary) buffer:

```
var file = [];
...
.on('data', function(data) {
  file.push(data);
})
.on('end', function() {
  file = Buffer.concat(file);
  ...
});
```

Comment: do u think the way i was doing it with strings is a problem even if the response IS in fact utf8 ?

Comment: @yoyoma PDF's may contain binary data, they're not completely 100% UTF-8 encoded (the _text_ in the PDF's may be, but there's lots of other stuff inside a PDF).

Comment: thx a lot this is the one that worked so marked it correct - i had tried various buffers before but i dont think i did the concat correctly

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to do something after the file is done being written by pipe, you can add an event listener for `finish` on the object returned by pipe.

```
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./report.pdf'))
.on('finish', function done() { /* the file has been written */ });
```

Source: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish